# Which planets have abundant amounts of photoluminiscent matter?

Tags: planet, light

Which planets have abundant amounts of photoluminiscent matter? Photoluminiscent or chemoluminiscent whatever the glow-in-the-dark stuff it may be. Planets or bodies which have good enough the photoluminiscence(light absorb and then release) property.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but none of the planets have substantial amounts of phosphorescent chemicals.

Perhaps the closest to what you are thinking is the aurora, which can be seen on all the planets with atmospheres (to a greater or lesser degree) notably on the Gas Giants and on Earth. However, while the mechanism of aurora is similar to florescence, it is not phosphorescence.

No planets outside of the solar system have been directly imaged beyond a dim dot, so there is no information about exoplanets.

Comment: "so there is no information about exoplanets." Spectra?

Comment: exoplanets are detected by their transits, or other indirect methods. To get a spectrum one would need to "see" the planet directly. There are few direct observations of exoplanets, and none of terrestrial expolanets. Not enough to get a spectrum. Rocky planets are probably composed of silicates, olivines, feldspars etc much like the planets of the solar system.

Comment: You can do transits in different bands and compare depths and widths. This is called transit spectroscopy. A reference is https://www.eso.org/sci/meetings/2014/exoelt2014/presentations/LopezMorales.pdf, this team publishes nice papers about that. Emission spectro exists as well, but I agree with you that probably we wouldn't see anything from terrestrial bodies yet. Maybe even not with JWST.

Comment: [For the first time, astronomers detected the fluorescent signature of HD 189733b which is an exoplanet](https://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2010/0203/In-distant-planet-s-fluorescent-glow-a-new-way-to-look-for-life)

Answer (score 1):

**Earth**

That is the only place in the universe we know there is stuff that glows in the dark.

[image]

More serious though, the only possible place I can think of is [Io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_%28moon%29). There may be some reactions taking place in the sulphur material ejected from the volcanoes that produces light.

[image]

Comment: You might find phosphorescent metal sulfides http://www.google.com/patents/US2544507 on Io. I've tried making my own phosphorescent Calcium sulfide, and it isn't easy. The stuff is likely to be rare on most planets and moons.

Comment: Other moons which glows are [Europa](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2020/11/jupiter-europa-glow/617056/) and [Titan](https://www.space.com/18308-saturn-moon-titan-glow-cassini.html).